# mysql query retuning only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query running on page that for some reason I sonly returning 1 row when run on my PHP application.

But when running the exact same query within PHP my admin it returns the correct number of rows.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
    include ('includes/headFunctions.php'); 
    include('includes/head.php');
?>

<div class="row container">

<?php
if(isset($_POST['weekly_search'])) {

    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];    

    $reporting = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-17'");

    if(!$reporting->count()) {
        echo 'No results';   
    } else {
        $_SESSION['weekly_records'] = 'true';
        //if I run the foreach here it works correctly
    }
}

    $week_start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last Sunday'));
    $week_end_date = date("Y-m-d");

    //echo $start_date, '<br>';
    //echo $end_date;
    //die();

            $results = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '$week_start_date' AND '$week_end_date'");       

            if ($results) {

                    $add = 0;
                    $minus = 0;
                    $total_transAdded = 0;
                    $total_transRedeemed = 0;

                    foreach ($results->results() as $result) {
                        $add = $total_transAdded += $result->transaction_add;
                        $minus = $total_transRedeemed += $result->transaction_redeem;
                    };

                    //print Elements
                    echo '<div class="row"><h1>Week Ending:</br> ', $week_end_date, '</h1></div>';
                    echo '<div class="row">';
                    echo '<div class="col-xs-6"><h2>Rewarded</h2>', '<h3>£', round ($add, 2), '</h3></div>';
                    echo '<div class="col-xs-6"><h2>Redeemed</h2></div>', '<h3>£', round ($minus, 2), '</h3></div>';
                    echo '</div>';

            } else {
                echo '<div class="error">No records found</div>';
            } //end if search->data

?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#date_picker_modal">Search By Date</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- End row container -->


<!-- Report Generator Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="date_picker_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Transaction</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Start Date</span>
                        <input type="date" min='0001-01-01' max='9999-12-31' name="start_date" class="form-control" step="any" min="0" required>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">End Date</span>
                        <input type="date" min='0001-01-01' max='9999-12-31' name="end_date" class="form-control" step="any" min="0" required>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="weekly_search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['weekly_records'])) {?>

<!-- Report Generator Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="weekly_records" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reports</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer</th><th>Added</th><th>Redeemed</th><th>Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <?php
                            //running the foreacheach only retunrs the last result
                            foreach($reporting->results() as $report) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td><a href="cust_history.php?custid=',$report->cust_id, '">View</a></td>';
                                echo '<td>£', round($report->transaction_add, 2), '</td>';
                                echo '<td>£', round($report->transaction_redeem, 2), '</td>';
                                echo '<td>', $report->transaction_date, '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }

                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>




<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is the least of your concerns.  Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and use query parameters and prepared statements instead of directly executing user input as code.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I know this, haven't got around to implementing it yet. Will do soon though

Comment: Please provide the source codes of your `query()`, `count()` and `results()` methods.

Comment: Please see my edit to the comment, I have found the problem, just not sure how to solve it.

Comment: You have to add further code since we don't know where "further down the page" is and what other code you have in your php scripts.

Comment: Apologies, I have now added the entire page to the post.

Comment: Keep in mind that `$week_end_date` is not the end of the week but the current date. This means that the window of dates you are looking at might be very small, which results in fewer results.

Comment: @Progman the week_end_date is used for another part of the system, it works as the current data as the system is accessed at the end of each week the current date is fine.

Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($reporting->results() as $report) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td><a href="cust_history.php?custid=',$report->cust_id, '">View</a></td>';
                                echo '<td>£', round($report->transaction_add, 2), '</td>';
                                echo '<td>£', round($report->transaction_redeem, 2), '</td>';
                                echo '<td>', $report->transaction_date, '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed?

Comment: Nope, still getting the same response.

Comment: The reporting variable is now report

Comment: @Chris Hinds in your code, each time you run the loop you overwrite the query result ($reporting variable). So you have to change to foreach ($reporting->results() as $other_variable_name_than_$reporting) {....}